# How to add text and caption Jssor slider

Tags: jssor

I would like to format a slider so that a text title appears above the image and a button appears below. Is it possible create a slider similar to the attached screenshot[image]?

Answer (score 6):

You can place any html code in each slide,

```
<div u="slides">
    <div>
        <img u="image" src="url" />
        <div style="position: absolute; top: npx; left: npx; width: npx; height: npx;">
            Your text here
        </div>
        <div class="yourbutton" style="position: absolute; top: npx; left: npx; width: npx; height: npx;">
            Your button text
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```